# Ubuntu 12.04 won't recognise my 2 monitors

Tags: graphics, display

I've got 2 monitors plugged into my nvidia quadro fx1700 graphics card but Ubuntu only recognises my HD monitor (says its a laptop monitor) and ignores the other one. Is there any way I can force it to recognise the other monitor? I have seen on other posts that the laptop thingis just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing these settings for nvidia, in terminal type :

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

and create a x-screen profile for the monitor.

Comment: I have done that but the other screen is just white and when I move my mouse onto the screen it becomes a cross

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my father's computer. What did the trick was to go into the dash and type: `Nvidia X Server Settings`. Open it and then go into the tab `X Server Display Configuration`.  Tick `enable` for `Xinerama`. Then click `apply`. To make this permanent, click `Save to X Configuration File` You may have to reboot afterwards for it to take affect. If it still doesn't work, play with the settings in here. It may be that it is configured that the other monitor is off. It is all fairly straitforward.

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings]

Hope this helps you!